# Google maps iframe loading very slow

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, iframe

I have written an article in wordpress and have used google iframe to load country maps of 35 countries. In other words, i am loading 35 iframes of google maps along with 100 other 640px medium size images. The size of the article i wrote is about 31 mb.

It takes about 15 seconds for the article to load, even worse in mobile browsers. Sometimes google maps causes the article content to stop loading for a long time.

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d5662268.557666768!2d-2.2908874246415487!3d46.135220605972364!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0xd54a02933785731%3A0x6bfd3f96c747d9f7!2sFrance!5e0!3m2!1sen!2shu!4v1483719195954" width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

How do i speed up the loading? Is there any simple way to do this?

I have used wordpress plugins like lazy load, but it only makes loading even worse and gets stuck. I a supe using supercache for wordpress.

Comment: Could you use static images instead of Google Maps API?

Comment: how to generate static maps?

Comment: I meant taking a screenshot of the map and using an image instead of an actual map.  If the maps aren't meant to be manipulated.

Comment: Any other solution to iframes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code should work. I've tested this and also added a timeout before each frame load so you can see the change.

```
var URLs = [
    'http://localhost/a.htm',
    'http://localhost/b.htm',
    'http://localhost/c.htm',
    'http://localhost/d.htm'
];

function loadNext(){

    var frameWindow = document.getElementById('test').contentWindow;

    if(URLs.length > 0){
        setTimeout(function(){
            frameWindow.location.replace(URLs.shift());
        }, 1000);
    }
}

<iframe id="test" onload="loadNext();"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the `<img>` tag instead of `<iframe>`!

Example:

```
<img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=London&zoom=13&scale=false&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap&format=png&visual_refresh=true"></img>
```

Outputs:

[image]

[Learn more](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro)

Comment: The above code is not working in my site, why? image fails to load. do i need api key?

Comment: If you have, you can but it's unnecessary. If it doesn't work, take a look at [http://staticmapmaker.com/google/](http://staticmapmaker.com/google/)

Comment: I'm hungarian, too :)

Comment: Nice )) yes i live in Hungary but i am indian :) Many thanks for your help J

Answer (score 1):

I think the only solution to load 100 images and 35 iframes is to use Lazy Load.

Lazy load supports iframes and images also. You can try one of free lazy load plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/bj-lazy-load/

I hope it help.

Comment: I tried it and still slow. I found a way around it. I used `defer`  in the iframe and i am happy with the speed.

Comment: `<iframe defer src=""..`